# Social connections for 2 domains to same site

Tags: facebook, twitter, instagram-api

I have 2 domains to the same site, one for a swedish version and one for a english version of the site.

I have an option for the user to connect with Facebook, Google, Instagram.

Now to my problem, should i create a app for each of my domains?

The problem with create one app for my swedish domain and one app for my english domain is when users create an account on the swedish site and then go to my english site needs to accept the permissions again and i need to store 2 social connections in the database, example for Facebook.

One problem to only have one app for both my swedish and my english site, is that settings for the apps (Instagram for example), can i only allow one domain to make calls.

What is the best way to go? One app for both my sites or one app for each site?

Comment: That’s correct, Facebook basically just allows one domain per app. (There are a few hacky ways around it to get it working with a couple more, but I would not recommend that.) You could however redirect users of your domain B to domain A for FB login, and then redirect them back to B after that’s done.

Comment: Thanx. Yes, i can do, but i use other funktions like load albums/images from facebook with javascript. So, the best way is to create 2 apps and then have a field in the database which tells if the user has connected on the swedish or the english site?